# Optimize Jaccard distance performance with numba

Tags: python, performance, numba

I am trying to implement the fastest possible version of jaccard distance in python using Numba

```
@nb.jit()
def nbjaccard(seq1, seq2):
    set1, set2 = set(seq1), set(seq2)
    return 1 - len(set1 & set2) / float(len(set1 | set2))

def jaccard(seq1, seq2):
    set1, set2 = set(seq1), set(seq2)
    return 1 - len(set1 & set2) / float(len(set1 | set2))


%%timeit
nbjaccard("compare this string","compare a different string")
```

--12.4 ms

```
%%timeit 
jaccard("compare this string","compare a different string")
```

--3.87 ms

Why does the numba version take longer? Any way to get a speedup?

Comment: I am not sure if the measure includes the jitting time. Perhaps by triggering a jit before the timing session could clarify some of the issue:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/jit.html#eager-compilation

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it was a bit of a design mistake to allow *pure* object-mode numba functions (or that there is no warning if numba realizes the whole function uses python objects) - because these are typically a bit slower than pure python functions.

Numba is very powerful (the type dispatching and that you can write python code without type declarations - compared to C extensions or Cython - is really great) but only when it supports the operation:

- [Supported Python features in numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html)
- [Supported NumPy features in numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html)

That means any operation that isn't listed there is not supported in the "nopython" mode. And if numba has to fall back to the ["object mode"](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/glossary.html#term-object-mode) then beware:

> **object mode**
>
> A Numba compilation mode that generates code that handles all values as Python objects and uses the Python C API to perform all operations on those objects. Code compiled in object mode will often run no faster than Python interpreted code, unless the Numba compiler can take advantage of loop-jitting.

And that's exactly what happened in your case: You operate purely in object mode:

```
>>> nbjaccard.inspect_types()

[...]
# --- LINE 3 --- 
#   seq1 = arg(0, name=seq1)  :: pyobject
#   seq2 = arg(1, name=seq2)  :: pyobject
#   $0.1 = global(set: <class 'set'>)  :: pyobject
#   $0.3 = call $0.1(seq1)  :: pyobject
#   $0.4 = global(set: <class 'set'>)  :: pyobject
#   $0.6 = call $0.4(seq2)  :: pyobject
#   set1 = $0.3  :: pyobject
#   set2 = $0.6  :: pyobject

set1, set2 = set(seq1), set(seq2)

# --- LINE 4 --- 
#   $const0.7 = const(int, 1)  :: pyobject
#   $0.8 = global(len: <built-in function len>)  :: pyobject
#   $0.11 = set1 & set2  :: pyobject
#   $0.12 = call $0.8($0.11)  :: pyobject
#   $0.13 = global(float: <class 'float'>)  :: pyobject
#   $0.14 = global(len: <built-in function len>)  :: pyobject
#   $0.17 = set1 | set2  :: pyobject
#   $0.18 = call $0.14($0.17)  :: pyobject
#   $0.19 = call $0.13($0.18)  :: pyobject
#   $0.20 = $0.12 / $0.19  :: pyobject
#   $0.21 = $const0.7 - $0.20  :: pyobject
#   $0.22 = cast(value=$0.21)  :: pyobject
#   return $0.22

return 1 - len(set1 & set2) / float(len(set1 | set2))
```

As you can see every single operation is operating on Python objects (as indicated by the `:: pyobject` at the end of each line). That's because `numba` doesn't support `str`s and `set`s. So there is absolutly nothing that could be faster here. Except you have an idea how to solve this problem using numpy arrays or homogeneous lists (of numerical type).

On my computer the time difference is much bigger (using numba 0.32.0) but the individual timings are much faster - **micro**seconds (`10**-6` seconds) instead of **milli**seconds (`10**-3` seconds):

```
%timeit nbjaccard("compare this string","compare a different string")
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.4 µs per loop

%timeit jaccard("compare this string","compare a different string")
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.9 µs per loop
```

Note that `jit` by default is [lazy](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#lazy-compilation), so the first call should be done before you time the execution - because it includes the time to compile the code.

---

Nevertheless there's one optimization you could do: If you know the intersection of two sets you can calculate the length of the union (as @Paul Hankin mentioned in his *now deleted* answer):

```
len(union) = len(set1) + len(set2) - len(intersection)
```

This would lead to the following (pure-python) code:

```
def jaccard2(seq1, seq2):
    set1, set2 = set(seq1), set(seq2)
    num_intersection = len(set1 & set2)
    return 1 - num_intersection / float(len(set1) + len(set2) - num_intersection)

%timeit jaccard2("compare this string","compare a different string")
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.7 µs per loop
```

Not much faster - but better.

---

There's some room for improvements, if you use [cython](/questions/tagged/cython):

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython
def cyjaccard(seq1, seq2):
    cdef set set1 = set(seq1)
    cdef set set2 = set()
    
    cdef Py_ssize_t length_intersect = 0
    
    for char in seq2:
        if char not in set2:
            if char in set1:
                length_intersect += 1
            set2.add(char)
            
    return 1 - (length_intersect / float(len(set1) + len(set2) - length_intersect))

%timeit cyjaccard("compare this string","compare a different string")
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.97 µs per loop
```

The main advantage here is that with only one iteration you can create `set2` and calculate the number of elements in the intersection (without needing to create the intersection set at all)!

Answer (score 1):

When I time these two function, `nbjaccard` takes ~4.7 microseconds (after warming up the jit) and the plain python one takes ~3.2 microseconds using Numba 0.32.0. That said, I don't expect numba to give you any speed-up in this case since there is basically no string support in `nopython` mode currently. That means you're going through the python object layer, which is typically no different than running without the jit, unless numba can do some smart loop lifting (that is compile a sub-block using pure intrinsics rather than python functions). You're probably just paying some small overhead in addition for type checking the inputs in the numba case.

I think the bottom line is that you're attempting to use numba for a use-case that currently isn't covered. Where Numba really excels is dealing with numpy arrays and operations on numerical scalar values or problems that can be pushed to a GPU.